# Get the specific response parameter with urllib in python

Tags: python, json, response, urllib

I am able to perform a web request and get back the response, using urllib.

```
from urllib import request
from urllib.parse import urlencode
response = request.urlopen(req, data=login_data)
content = response.read()
```

I get back something like `b'{"token":"abcabcabc","error":null}'`

How will i be able to parse the token information?

Comment: you can use `json.loads(bin_data)['token']`

Comment: Thanks! If you want, you can make this an answer, so i can give you the points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to load the binary string data and then access the `token` property:

```py
token = json.loads(bin_data)['token']
```